# undefined: grpc.ClientConnInterface when compiling grpc

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go

I am new to grpc. In my `go.mod` file I have:

```
google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20190508193815-b515fa19cec8
google.golang.org/grpc v1.21.1
github.com/gogo/protobuf v1.2.2-0.20190723190241-65acae22fc9d
github.com/golang/protobuf v1.3.2
```

I am generating my protobufs like this:

```
go get google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go
go get google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc
protoc --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=. ./me.proto
```

I get the following errors when I try to run tests and build:

```
me_grpc.pb.go:15:11: undefined: grpc.SupportPackageIsVersion7
me_grpc.pb.go:25:5: undefined: grpc.ClientConnInterface
me_grpc.pb.go:28:30: undefined: grpc.ClientConnInterface
me_grpc.pb.go:65:34: undefined: grpc.ServiceRegistrar
```

I figured out that switching `SupportPackageIsVersion7` to `SupportPackageIsVersion5` makes gopls happy but I have no idea what I need to do in order to make the other errors go away. Unfortunately, I am stuck at the versions of the libraries in my go.mod file due to other things in my repo that fail to compile if I try to upgrade those libraries.

Comment: It is unclear if the other modules of the go.mod are loaded. It might be required to go get grpc and genproto.

Comment: what was it different Fredrich's answer from my answer ?!  and why you confirm bounty for this answer ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
replace (
   github.com/coreos/etcd => github.com/ozonru/etcd v3.3.20-grpc1.27-origmodule+incompatible
   google.golang.org/grpc => google.golang.org/grpc v1.27.0
)
```

in go.mod should help

Comment: I got away with fixing all errors by just updating the `google.golang.org/grpc` to `v1.27.0`

Answer (score 5):

It's good that you started GRPC.

It seems like you're `protoc-gen-go` is old and needed to be updated,

to update it you should

- first, remove the current one, to find where it is stored, you can use the `echo $PATH`  command to find out where this file is. then remove it.
- second, install the new one, for installing it you can run this command.

  `go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc`

  **Note** If you have any problem getting it, use this command instead,

  `go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go`

after the update, you must edit your `go.mod` file.

change this line:

```
google.golang.org/grpc v1.21.1
```

to

```
google.golang.org/grpc v1.33.2
```

This version (`1.33.2`) supports `SupportPackageIsVersion7` and your problem will be solved.

**Note:** `SupportPackageIsVersion7` support after `1.32.0` versions. and they support old versions with `go version >= 1.12`

thanks, @bithavoc for the useful comment:
to see the latest version, just look for the version on top of [pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc)

Comment: Thank you but I am unable to upgrade to a better version. I have a LOT of dependencies that are out of my control that I am unable to upgrade.

Comment: @user_78361084 Did you try to change this line `google.golang.org/grpc v1.21.1`?

Comment: Like I said, I am not able to upgrade any of my packages. I have to build with what is in the go.mod file. Changing that line causes a lot of issues in other packages.

Comment: @user_78361084 This update hadn't any conflict with older versions. Your old version is `1.21.1` that supports `SupportPackageIsVersion5`, the version `1.33.2` also support `SupportPackageIsVersion from 3 to 7`. so you are free to use the new version

Comment: Why does it generate version 7, though?

Comment: @user_78361084 `grpc.SupportPackageIsVersion` is used to track the version of the protobuf generated code and is different from the grpc release version.

Comment: to see the latest version, just look for the version on top of https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc